# Interfaces, properties and procedure of object FPC

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

While implementing my own observer framework I got a problem: I can't execute procedures of object when they are returned in getter. I have here an example program for Lazarus. What should I do to see "TRUE" in console? (Now program returns false). It's a complete program, you can just copy-paste it.

```
program project1;

{$mode objfpc}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

type

  TEvent = procedure of object;

  { IInterface }

  IInterface = interface
    function GetEvent: TEvent;
    procedure SetEvent(AValue: TEvent);
    property Event: TEvent read GetEvent write SetEvent;
  end;

  { TMYClass }

  TMYClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface)
  private
    FEvent: TEvent;
  public
    function GetEvent: TEvent;
    procedure SetEvent(AValue: TEvent);
    property Event: TEvent read GetEvent write SetEvent;
  end;

  { TAnotherClass }

  TAnotherClass = class
    FVariable: boolean;
    constructor Create;
    procedure Handler;
  end;

  { TAnotherClass }

  constructor TAnotherClass.Create;
  begin
    FVariable := False;
  end;

  procedure TAnotherClass.Handler;
  begin
    FVariable := True;
  end;

  function TMYClass.GetEvent: TEvent;
  begin
    Result := FEvent;
  end;

  procedure TMYClass.SetEvent(AValue: TEvent);
  begin
    FEvent := AValue;
  end;

var
  LInterface: IInterface;
  LAnother: TAnotherClass;

begin
  LInterface := TMYClass.Create;
  LAnother := TAnotherClass.Create;
  LInterface.Event:=@LAnother.Handler;
  LInterface.Event;
  WriteLn(LAnother.FVariable);
  ReadLn();
end.
```

When I debug this, it looks as if Result isn't assigned in TMYClass.GetEvent. Do you know, what is my problem?

Comment: Call procedure like `LInterface.Event();`

Comment: @Abelisto it works! Thank you!

Comment: PS: When you deal with pointers to code in many cases it is necessary to explicitly say to compiler that you want to call the code instead of reference the pointer. Use parenthesis for that.

Comment: Another solution of course is change mode to "Delphi"